Debugging a .NET 7 app running in Docker container (WSL2) in VS Code 'fetch failed'
I haven't had a need for a couple of months to debug one of my apps running in Docker container.
Last time everything worked and I had no issues.
Currently, when I try to Run and Debug with Docker .NET Attach (Preview) configuration first I get the Acquiring .NET Debugger notification and a moment later I receive an error in VS code fetch failed.

I already tried removing the ~/.vsdbg from my WSL2 Ubuntu. I tried reinstalling the Docker extension in VS Code. None of those two worked.
Here's my Dockerfile file
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

COPY src/zscaler.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/zscaler.crt
RUN update-ca-certificates

#copy all csproj files and restore as distinct layers. Use the same COPY command
#for every dockerfile in the project to take andvantage of docker caching

COPY XYZ.sln XYZ.sln
COPY src/123/123.csproj src/123/123.csproj
COPY src/SearchService/SearchService.csproj src/SearchService/SearchService.csproj
COPY src/456/456.csproj src/456/456.csproj
COPY src/789/789.csproj src/789/789.csproj
COPY src/ABC/ABC.csproj src/ABC/ABC.csproj

# Restore package deps
RUN dotnet restore XYZ.sln

# Copy the app folders over
COPY src/SearchService src/SearchService
COPY src/789 src/789
WORKDIR /app/src/SearchService
RUN dotnet publish -c Debug -o /app/src/out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/src/out .
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "SearchService.dll" ]

and my .vscode/launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Docker .NET Attach (Preview)",
            "type": "docker",
            "request": "attach",
            "platform": "netCore",
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/app": "${workspaceFolder}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/SearchService/bin/Debug/net7.0/SearchService.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src/SearchService",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "openExternally",
                "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach"
        }
    ]
}

